# Different models do incremental fit for RNN model while hyperparameter tuning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, hyperparameters

I am quite new to deep learning and I was studying [this RNN example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSpXCRTOLJA).

After completing the tutorial, I decided to see the effect of various hyperparameters such as the number of nodes in each layer and dropout factor etc.

What I do is, for each value in my lists, create a new model using a set of parameters and test the performance in my dataset. Below is the basic code:

```
def build_model(MODELNAME, l1,l2,l3, l4, d):
    tf.global_variables_initializer() 
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    model = Sequential(name = MODELNAME)
    model.reset_states

    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(l1, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True) )
    model.add(Dropout(d))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(l2, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True) )

    # Definition of other layers of the model ...

    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                 optimizer=opt,
                 metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                        validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
    return model

layer1 = [64, 128, 256]
layer2,3,4 = [...]
drop = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4


for l1 in layer1:
     #for l2, l3, l4 for layer2, layer3, layer4  
        for d in drop:
            sess = tf.Session(config=config)
            set_session(sess)

            MODELNAME = 'RNN-l1={}-l2={}-l3={}-l4={}-drop={} '.format(l1, l2, l3, l4, d)
            print(MODELNAME)

            model = build_model(MODELNAME, l1,l2,l3, l4, d)
            sess.close()
            print('-----> training & validation loss & accuracies)
```

The problem is when the new model is built using the new parameters, it works as if the next epoch of the previous model, rather than epoch 1 of the new one. Below is some of the results.

```
RNN-l1=64-l2=64-l3=64-l4=32-drop=0.2 
Train on 90116 samples, validate on 4458 samples
Epoch 1/6
90116/90116 [==============================] - 139s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5558 - acc: 0.7116 - val_loss: 0.8857 - val_acc: 0.5213
... # results for other epochs
Epoch 6/6
RNN-l1=64-l2=64-l3=64-l4=32-drop=0.3 
90116/90116 [==============================] - 140s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5233 - acc: 0.7369 - val_loss: 0.9760 - val_acc: 0.5336
Epoch 1/6
90116/90116 [==============================] - 142s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5170 - acc: 0.7403 - val_loss: 0.9671 - val_acc: 0.5310
... # results for other epochs
90116/90116 [==============================] - 142s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4953 - acc: 0.7577 - val_loss: 0.9587 - val_acc: 0.5354
Epoch 6/6
90116/90116 [==============================] - 143s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4908 - acc: 0.7614 - val_loss: 1.0319 - val_acc: 0.5397
# -------------------AFTER 31TH SET OF PARAMETERS
RNN-l1=64-l2=256-l3=128-l4=32-drop=0.2
Epoch 1/6
90116/90116 [==============================] - 144s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1080 - acc: 0.9596 - val_loss: 1.8910 - val_acc: 0.5372
```

As seen, the first epoch of 31th set of parameters behaves as if it is 181th epoch. Similarly, if I stop the run at one point and re-run again, the accuracy and loss look as if it is the next epoch as below.

```
Epoch 1/6
90116/90116 [==============================] - 144s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1053 - acc: 0.9621 - val_loss: 1.9120 - val_acc: 0.5375
```

I tried a bunch of things (as you can see in the code), such as `model=None`, `reinitializing the variables`, `resetting_status of the model`, `closing session in each iteration` etc but none helped. I searched for similar question with no luck.

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong. 
Any help is appreciated,

Note: Title is not very explanatory, I am open to suggestions for a better title.

Comment: Looks like you are using a Keras setting, which means you need to 
import keras backend and then clear that session before you run your new model. 
It would be something like this:

from keras import backend as K

K.clear_session()

Comment: Yes, it looks like that is the problem. You can submit this comment as an answer since it is the correct answer

Comment: sure! glad to help!

Comment: kvish, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using a Keras setting, which means you need to import keras backend and then clear that session before you run your new model. It would be something like this:

```
from keras import backend as K 
K.clear_session()
```